# Where is the ArcGIS Workflow Manager REST API documentation?

Tags: arcgis-server, api, arcgis-workflow-manager

I hope it is online and I'm just missing with my searches.

I'm looking for this API documentation for 10.0 (but I will +1 answers relating to the 10.1 version):
[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is as close as I could find for 10.0:

http://proceedings.esri.com/library/userconf/devsummit11/papers/tech/2011-b_1.pdf

Comment: That's where my screenshot came from.